# Is it possible to use a Word macro to replace one mail merge field with another?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have Word Mail Merge document with merge codes inserted. I was wondering if I can write a Word macro to search for one mail merge code and replace it with another? I have tried, but the merge code I replace reverts back to the original value.
I create a Word macro and use CTRL + H, put the data in to search and replace for(The merge fields) and click replace. It replaces the data, but after I save and return to document the old merge code is still there. The following vba code is generated:

```
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting 
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting 
  With Selection.Find 
    .Text = "F_400" 
    .Replacement.Text = "F_901" 
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
    .Format = False 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .MatchWholeWord = False 
    .MatchWildcards = False 
    .MatchSoundsLike = False 
    .MatchAllWordForms = False 
 End With 
 Selection.Find.Execute
```

I am replacing merge field F_400 with merge field F_901.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replace the name of a Mergefield you need to work with the underlying field code. What you normally see is a "pretty view" presented by Word, that can be switched between "field name" and the data preview provided by the Mailings tab in the Ribbon.

In order to use Find/Replace directly on the field codes, use Alt+F9 to toggle to the field code view. You should then see { MERGEFIELD fieldname }. In this state, you can Find fieldname and Replace it with a different, valid field name from the data source.

In order to toggle the field codes display as part of a macro so that you can use Find/Replace in VBA, use a Window object with the View.ShowFieldCodes property, for example:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True 'False to turn them off
```

This works fine when using Selection.Find. For Range.Find there's an alternate approach, by changing the TextRetrievalMode for the Range object being used for the Find:

```
rngFind.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes
With rngFind
   'and so on
```

The IncludeFieldCodes property picks up the "hidden" field codes for the code processing, so it doesn't matter whether the field codes are displayed on-screen, or not.

Comment: Thank you Cindy. I have this working using arrays and iterating through the document to change the merge codes in a loop. I guess clicking on grey arrow and making it green indicates it is answered?

Comment: @KentE Yep, grey->green does it :-) Thanks! Also, on StackOverflow clicking an up-arrow (just above the checkmark) indicates "appreciation" - anywhere you see a question or answer you find good/helpful. Down arrow = "thumbs down" when you think something is poor quality.